# Would it be more secure to have untrusted applications execute on a type 1 or a type 2 hypervisor?

Tags: virtualization

My usual workflow is to run potentially malicious applications/websites (untrusted) inside of a virtualbox VM. Lately I have been playing with hyper-v. From what I gather, critical windows components are running in a VM (with Defender System Guard) and the "rest" of windows is in another VM. I then have two options: have the  "untrusted" VM alongside the Windows VMs on Hyper-V, or have a separate "untrusted" virtualbox VM on top of the host OS. Would either of those options be more secure than the other? What are the chances of something breaking out of hyper-v VM and into another hyper-v VM (or the hypervisor itself)?

While I mention specific technologies, I guess the question boils down to this: would it be more secure to have untrusted applications execute on a type 1 or a type 2 hypervisor? Is there any greater risk of something breaking out of a type 1 and affecting the rest of the system?